# An expression whose value can be 'null' must be null-checked before it can be dereferenced

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I am using Dart with null-safity mode. I have porblem in next code.

```
List<JobModel> _jobList = [];
// ...
if(_jobList.isNotEmpty) { 
  for(var job in _jobList) {
     if(job.cmd_args != null) {
       numbersOfAlreadyActiveJobs.addAll(job.cmd_args.replaceAll('(', '').replaceAll(')','').split('=')[1].split(',').map(int.parse).toList());
     }  
  }
```

I
am getting next error:

[image]

But why? I am doing check of `job.cmd_args != null`

Comment: job.cmd_args?.replaceAll

Comment: or, if cmd_args can not be null, you could use job.cmd_args!.replaceAll

Answer (score 1):

Dart promotes local variables only, this goes both for types and null-ness.

When you do `if (job.cmd_args != null) ...`, it doesn't allow the compiler to assume that any later evaluation of `job.cmd_args` will also return a non-null value. It cannot know that without knowing the entire program (to ensure that nothing implements a `JobModel` where `cmd_args` might be a getter which does something different on the next call). Even if it knows that, we don't want local type promotion to depend on global information. That makes it too fragile and you can't depend on it. Someone adding a class somewhere else might make your code no longer promote, and therefore no longer compile.

So, your test is not enough.

What you can do is either say "I know what I'm doing" and add a `!` to `job.cmd_args!.replaceAll`. That's a run-time cast to a non-nullable type, and it will throw if the value ends up actually being `null` on the second read (which it probably won't, but compilers aren't satisfied by "probably"s).

Alternatively, you can introduce a local variable, which *can* be promoted to non-null:

```dart
var args = job.cmd_args;
if (args != null) { 
  numberOfAlreadyActiveJobs.addAll(args.replaceAll(...));
}
```

Here you introduce a new *local* variable, `args`, and then you check whether *that* is `null`. If it isn't, then you can safely use it as non-`null` later because a local variable can't be affected by code anywhere else, so the compiler believes it really will have the same value when you use it later.